# how to define jquery in wordpress template

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

how to define jquery in my new wordpress theme all i know that jquery not define so all plugin that work with the jquery not work sush as faser image insert or jquery accordion menu vertical
and any popup windows in wordpress cpanil 
itry to add

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

before

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

and try to add this line in function.php

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

do i do it right way

how can i know that jquery define in the theme ? or what is the conflict might it happen to deactivate the jquery in all site

Answer (score 0):

You can check if jQuery is included in Google Chrome. Just use inspect element, you should see a script tag (with the jquery file in the src, you can check it to verify if code is really there) somewhere in the head tag or at the end of the body.

Your code looks about right, but it might have errors. It's better to check the actual page. Also, remember that you should include jQuery before your other jQuery plugins.

And one more thing, I think it would be better to use WordPress's jQuery to make sure you don't introduce bugs or incompatibilities with the one from Google. You can do this by putting this in functions.php

```
function insert_jquery(){
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_filter('wp_head','insert_jquery');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own scripts in wp and jQuery might not work together too well. You should use jQuery's [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode! (I'm sorry for the rather poor content but I'm on mobile now. Will add sources and example later.)

You can use it as a var, like such:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("form#searchform input[type=text]").focus(function() {
        $j(this).animate({
            width: "140px"
        }, 400);
    });
    $j("form#searchform input[type=text]").blur(function() {
        $j(this).animate({
            width: "60px"
        }, 400);
    });
});
```